# Android Studio onClick Set Text issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an MPG conversion where the user enters their amount of miles as an integer and their amount of liters they have topped up their car by as a double. A `submit` button click will divide miles by litres and provide me with an MPG figure.

My Code:

```
final EditText mileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Mileage);
final EditText litres = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.litres);
final Button mpg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_MPG);
final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mpg_result);

mpg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer miles = Integer.parseInt(mileage.toString());
        Double litre = Double.parseDouble(litres.toString());
        Double answer = Double.parseDouble(result.getText().toString());

        answer = miles / litre;

        result.setText(answer);
    }
});
```

My issue is that I'm struggling to convert the user input into doubles and integers and then setting the result to a textview.

My AC:

- To be able to convert miles and liters into an MPG figure.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually converting:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int miles = Integer.parseInt(mileage.getText().toString());
    double litre = Double.parseDouble(litres.getText().toString());
    double answer = (double)miles / litre;

    result.setText((""+answer));
    ...
```

Here, I convert with `(double)miles / litre` and then set the `TextView` text to be the answer.

Comment: This is fantastic thank you for the feedback, I compared the code and understood what I had missed and mistaken as well.

Comment: `(double)miles` is not required

Answer (score 1):

You are not retrieving the values from `edittext` ,To retrieve the value ,use `getText()`

```
Integer miles = Integer.parseInt(mileage.getText().toString());
Double litre = Double.parseDouble(litres.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
Integer miles = Integer.parseInt(mileage.toString());
Double litre = Double.parseDouble(litres.toString());
```

No need of

```
Double answer = Double.parseDouble(result.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `mileage.getText().toString()`